# Google Sheets IMPORTXML not working for website scraping (XPATH issue)

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying to retrieve APR information from this website https://tomb.finance/cemetery/TshareFtmLPTShareRewardPool using Google Sheets, but it returns `#N/A`

I used the Inspect > Copy XPath options to get the results, using the command as follows:

> Cell A1: https://tomb.finance/cemetery/TshareFtmLPTShareRewardPool
> Cell B1: //*[@id="root"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/p[2]
> `=IMPORTXML(A1,B1)`

And I have also tried 'Copy full XPath'

> Cell B1: /html/body/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div

Don't have a programming background, and this is getting a bit frustrating. Would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if it is possible here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun; the content is probably added dynamically by javascript, then native functions as importxml won't work.

Comment: Looks like this requires a login - if so you wont be able to import it into sheets like that on its own